# How to Make a cursor Type scroll insensitive in jdbc usin sqlite

Tags: java, database, sqlite, jdbc, scroll

Hey im attempting to to make an invoice program that uses Java and Sqlite as a database. I know that sqlite is a forward only language, but is there a way to scroll backwards or make it type scroll insensitive here is the class that im trying to use. I am attempting to put all of my information extracted from my database into an array.

```
 public String[] getRow(int rowID)
        {

                 String id =("");
                 String name = ("");
                 String day  = ("");
                 String location = ("");
                 String price = ("");
                 String timestart= ("");
                 String Timeend = ("");
                 String Showtype = ("");
          String[] row= new String[8];      
        try
          {  
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection x=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
            Statement stmt = x.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);  
           ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery ("SELECT ID, NAME, day, Location, price, timestart, Timeend, Showtype FROM Showinformation ORDER BY ID LIMIT 5 OFFSET:index;");
             rs.step(rowID);    


            while(rs.next()) 
                {


                for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
                {
                     id = rs.getString("ID");
                      row[0]=id;
                     name = rs.getString("NAME");
                      row[1]=name;
                     day  = rs.getString("day");
                       row[2]=day;
                     location = rs.getString("Location");
                       row[3]=location;
                     price = rs.getString("price");
                       row[4]=price;
                     timestart= rs.getString("timestart");
                        row[5]=timestart;
                     Timeend= rs.getString("Timeend");
                       row[6]=Timeend;
                     Showtype= rs.getString("Showtype");
                        row[7]=Showtype;



                }        
                     //String potato =(i+1+id+""+name+""+day+""+location+""+price+""+timestart+""+Timeend+""+Showtype);
                     //System.out.println("ID = " + id +"\nNAME = " + name+"\nDAY = " + day+"\nADDRESS = " + location+"\nPRICE = " + price+"\nTIME START = " + timestart+"\nTIME END = " + Timeend+"\nSHOWTYPE = " + Showtype );

                }


           }    

             catch(Exception er)
            {
                System.err.println(er.getClass().getName()+":"+er.getMessage() );
            }
          return row; 
         }
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you already have the data in the array, why do you need to scroll backwards?

Comment: As far as I know, sqlite only supports `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yeah i know that im looking for a work around.

Comment: @CL. the array is only filling up with the last thing i put into the database. I need to step back in order to access older entries.

Comment: Then make an array of arrays (or an `ArrayList` or whatever).

Comment: You'd either 1) need to write your own JDBC driver, or 2) use a `CachedRowSet` instead.

Comment: @CL. thats what im attempting to do. Im taking each row of the database and placing it into an array . then im taking that array and placing it into an arraylist.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel What exactly does would a CachedRowSet

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/cachedrowset.html